# How to layout Components when Conponent Size is needed beforehand (Java)

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, size

So the problem is this, I have a Project where I want to layout Components in a Panel and need to know the Size of the Panel beforehand so that I can scale the Panels on the Panel accordingly.
But as I have read in many posts and blogs it is not goot practice to work with any of the get*Size() Methods, but to let the LayoutManager do all this.
The Question is how should I tell my Panels how big they need to be and how they need to be resized, it is also neccessary that they keep their ratio at all times.

Since I can't really put any CodeSnipped in here because it would not work, I can show the Class which is responsible for calculating the size of the Panels. I altered the Code a little bit.

```
public class JColorCardPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7038017071626911475L;

    public JColorCardPanel() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    public void updateColorCardPanel(int maxPanelHeight) {
        this.removeAll();

        Map<TransportMode, SortedMap<Integer, List<ColorCard>>> rankingMap = new HashMap<>();
        SortedMap<Integer, List<ColorCard>> mapTrain = new TreeMap<>();
        mapTrain.put(3, List.of(new ColorCard(MyColor.PURPLE, TransportMode.TRAIN), new ColorCard(MyColor.RAINBOW, TransportMode.TRAIN), new ColorCard(MyColor.YELLOW, TransportMode.TRAIN)));
        mapTrain.put(4, List.of(new ColorCard(MyColor.BLACK, TransportMode.TRAIN), new ColorCard(MyColor.WHITE, TransportMode.TRAIN), new ColorCard(MyColor.RED, TransportMode.TRAIN),
                new ColorCard(MyColor.ORANGE, TransportMode.TRAIN), new ColorCard(MyColor.GREEN, TransportMode.TRAIN)));
        rankingMap.put(TransportMode.TRAIN, mapTrain);
        SortedMap<Integer, List<ColorCard>> mapShip = new TreeMap<>();
        mapShip.put(2, List.of(new ColorCard(MyColor.PURPLE, TransportMode.SHIP), new ColorCard(MyColor.RAINBOW, TransportMode.SHIP), new ColorCard(MyColor.BLACK, TransportMode.SHIP),
                new ColorCard(MyColor.WHITE, TransportMode.SHIP), new ColorCard(MyColor.YELLOW, TransportMode.SHIP)));
        mapShip.put(3, List.of(new ColorCard(MyColor.WHITE, TransportMode.SHIP), new ColorCard(MyColor.RED, TransportMode.SHIP), new ColorCard(MyColor.ORANGE, TransportMode.SHIP),
                new ColorCard(MyColor.GREEN, TransportMode.SHIP)));
        rankingMap.put(TransportMode.SHIP, mapShip);

        int padding = 5;
        double ratio = 2 / 3.0;
        int maxHeight = 150;
        int maxWidth = (int) (maxHeight * ratio);
        int height = 0;
        int width = 0;
        while (width <= (padding * 4)) {
            int maxColumnCount = rankingMap.values().stream().flatMap(t -> Stream.of(t.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).toList().size())).mapToInt(i -> i).max().getAsInt();
            int maxPossibleHeight = ((maxPanelHeight - 20) / maxColumnCount) - (2 * padding);
            int maxRowCount = rankingMap.values().stream().flatMap(t -> Stream.of(new ArrayList<>(t.keySet()).get(0))).reduce(0, (t, u) -> t + u);
            int maxPossibleWidth = ((this.getWidth() - 20) / maxRowCount) - (2 * padding);
            height = maxPossibleHeight > maxHeight ? maxHeight : maxPossibleHeight;
            width = maxPossibleWidth > maxWidth ? maxWidth : maxPossibleWidth;
            double proportion = width / (double) height;
            if (proportion < ratio) {
                height = (int) (width / ratio);
            } else {
                width = (int) (height * ratio);
            }
            padding--;
        }
        Dimension prefederredDimension = new Dimension(width, height);
        GridBagConstraints gbcTransport = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbcTransport.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        Iterator<Entry<TransportMode, SortedMap<Integer, List<ColorCard>>>> iteratorMap = rankingMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iteratorMap.hasNext()) {
            JPanel transportPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            transportPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            Entry<TransportMode, SortedMap<Integer, List<ColorCard>>> entryTransportMode = iteratorMap.next();
            Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<ColorCard>>> it = entryTransportMode.getValue().entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Entry<Integer, List<ColorCard>> entry = it.next();
                JColorCardLabel label;
                List<ColorCard> cards = entry.getValue();
                for (int i = 0, m = cards.size(); i < m; i++) {
                    ColorCard card = cards.get(i);
                    gbc.gridx = 0;
                    for (int j = 0, n = entry.getKey(); j < n; j++) {
                        if (card.color() == MyColor.RAINBOW) {
                            label = new JGradientLabel(card);
                        } else {
                            label = new JColorCardLabel(card);
                        }
                        label.setPreferredSize(prefederredDimension);
                        transportPanel.add(label, gbc);
                        gbc.gridx++;
                    }
                    gbc.gridy++;
                }
            }
            transportPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(), entryTransportMode.getKey().getDisplayNameSingular()));
            gbcTransport.gridx++;
            this.add(transportPanel, gbcTransport);
        }
        gbcTransport.weightx = 1;
        gbcTransport.weighty = 1;
        gbcTransport.gridx++;
        gbcTransport.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(new JPanel(), gbcTransport);
    }

    private static class JColorCardLabel extends JLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5607808287807778978L;

        public final ColorCard colorCard;

        public JColorCardLabel(ColorCard colorCard) {
            super(colorCard.getColorCardString());
            this.colorCard = colorCard;
            this.setForeground(colorCard.color().getComplementaryColor());
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 20));
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
            this.setBackground(colorCard.color().realColor);
            this.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
            this.setFocusable(false);
            this.setOpaque(true);
        }
    }

    public static class JGradientLabel extends JColorCardLabel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5469665614084730926L;

        public JGradientLabel(ColorCard colorCard) {
            super(colorCard);
            this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setBackground(null);
            this.setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            MyColor[] colors = MyColor.getNormalMyColors();
            int stripHeigth = this.getHeight() / (colors.length - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < (colors.length - 1); i++) {
                g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(0, i * stripHeigth), colors[i].realColor, new Point(0, (i + 1) * stripHeigth), colors[i + 1].realColor));
                g2.fillRect(0, i * stripHeigth, this.getWidth(), (i + 1) * stripHeigth);
            }
            g2.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the neede ColorCard Class:

```
public class ColorCard {

    private final MyColor color;
    private final TransportMode transportMode;

    public ColorCard(MyColor color, TransportMode transportMode) {
        this.color = color;
        this.transportMode = transportMode;
    }

    public MyColor color() {
        return this.color;
    }

    public TransportMode transportMode() {
        return this.transportMode;
    }

    public String getColorCardString() {
        return "<html><body>" + this.transportMode().getDisplayNameSingular() + "<br>" + this.color().getColorNameSingular() + "</body></html>";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.color, this.transportMode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) { return true; }
        if (obj == null) { return false; }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) { return false; }
        ColorCard other = (ColorCard) obj;
        return (this.color == other.color) && (this.transportMode == other.transportMode);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + this.color + ", " + this.transportMode + "]";
    }

    public enum MyColor {

        BLACK(LanguageKey.BLACK, LanguageKey.BLACKPLURAL, Color.BLACK),
        BLUE(LanguageKey.BLUE, LanguageKey.BLUEPLURAL, Color.BLUE),
        RED(LanguageKey.RED, LanguageKey.REDPLURAL, Color.RED),
        GREEN(LanguageKey.GREEN, LanguageKey.GREENPLURAL, Color.GREEN),
        YELLOW(LanguageKey.YELLOW, LanguageKey.YELLOWPLURAL, Color.YELLOW),
        PURPLE(LanguageKey.PURPLE, LanguageKey.PURPLEPLURAL, Color.MAGENTA),
        WHITE(LanguageKey.WHITE, LanguageKey.WHITEPLURAL, Color.WHITE),
        ORANGE(LanguageKey.ORANGE, LanguageKey.ORANGEPLURAL, Color.ORANGE),
        GRAY(LanguageKey.GRAY, LanguageKey.GRAY, Color.GRAY),
        RAINBOW(LanguageKey.RAINBOW, LanguageKey.RAINBOW, Color.MAGENTA);

        private final LanguageKey colorNameSingular;
        private final LanguageKey colorNamePlural;
        public final Color realColor;

        MyColor(LanguageKey colorNameSingular, LanguageKey colorNamePlural, Color realColor) {
            this.colorNameSingular = colorNameSingular;
            this.colorNamePlural = colorNamePlural;
            this.realColor = realColor;
        }

        public String getColorNameSingular() {
            return Application.resources.getString(this.colorNameSingular);
        }

        public String getColorNamePlural() {
            return Application.resources.getString(this.colorNamePlural);
        }

        public Color getRealColor() {
            return this.realColor;
        }

        public static MyColor getMyColor(String colorName) {
            return MyColor.valueOf(colorName.toUpperCase());
        }

        public static MyColor[] getNormalMyColors() {
            return Stream.of(MyColor.values()).filter(c -> (c != GRAY) && (c != RAINBOW)).toArray(MyColor[]::new);
        }

        public Color getComplementaryColor() {
            return MyColor.getComplementaryColor(this);
        }

        public static Color getComplementaryColor(MyColor myColor) {
            Color color = myColor.realColor;
            if (color == Color.WHITE) { return Color.BLACK; }
            if (color == Color.BLACK) { return Color.WHITE; }
            int r = color.getRed();
            int g = color.getGreen();
            int b = color.getBlue();
            int maxRGB = Math.max(r, Math.max(g, b));
            int minRGB = Math.min(r, Math.min(g, b));
            int addition = maxRGB + minRGB;
            return new Color(addition - r, addition - g, addition - b);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getColorNameSingular();
        }
    }

    public enum TransportMode implements Serializable {

        TRAIN(LanguageKey.TRAIN, LanguageKey.TRAINS, "t"),
        SHIP(LanguageKey.SHIP, LanguageKey.SHIPS, "s"),
        AIRPLANE(LanguageKey.AIRPLANE, LanguageKey.AIRPLANES, "a");

        private final LanguageKey displayNameSingular;
        private final LanguageKey displayNamePlural;
        public final String abbreviation;

        TransportMode(LanguageKey displayNameSingular, LanguageKey displayNamePlural, String abbreviation) {
            this.displayNameSingular = displayNameSingular;
            this.displayNamePlural = displayNamePlural;
            this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        }

        public String getDisplayNameSingular() {
            return Application.resources.getString(this.displayNameSingular);
        }

        public String getDisplayNamePlural() {
            return Application.resources.getString(this.displayNamePlural);
        }

        public static TransportMode getTransportMode(String abbreviation) {
            return Stream.of(TransportMode.values()).filter(t -> t.abbreviation.equalsIgnoreCase(abbreviation)).findAny().get();
        }
    }
}
```

My whole Project can be found on github under
https://github.com/MineRickStar/Zug-um-Zug.git

Any answer or comment on what I could change would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With this kind of question, it is probably a good idea to post a mock-up image of what you want your gui to look like

Comment: Thats a bit hard to describe, but something like that all Cards are equally spaced and all the same Size and Ratio, it should resize according to the size of the Component.

Comment: A `GridBagLayout` should make that doable. Just be careful of `weightx` and `weighty`

Comment: It is just not possible from my point of view to tell the Labels to keep the same ratio when  they are able to be scaled as the top component with the GridLayout says.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this and tell me if that's the resizing behaviour you want. If it's not I'll delete it

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class F extends JFrame {
    // NOT the same as GrinBagConstraints.gridwidth/gridheight
    private static final int GRID_WIDTH = 4;
    private static final int GRID_HEIGHT = 2;

    private void setGui() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container cp = getContentPane();
            cp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.weighty = 1.0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            for (int x = 0; x < F.GRID_WIDTH; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < F.GRID_HEIGHT; y++) {
                    gbc.gridx = x;
                    gbc.gridy = y;
                    cp.add(new Card(), gbc);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Card extends JPanel {
        public Card() {
            super();
            setBackground(new Color((int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(80, 80);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    F f = new F();
                    f.setGui();
                    f.pack();
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No this is also not it. I just take annother approach in displaying the Cards, but thanks for the effort.

Comment: Well can you tell me *why* it's wrong?